# How can I make an InputDecoration border appear only on the left?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to only show the pink border on the left side when focused.

This is what I currently have and it is showing on all sides:

```dart
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink, 
                    width: 2.0)
                 )
```

Comment: Can you remind me to answer this?

Comment: Do you need to show the left side only or to have a different color for the left side? You are using Material TextField?

Comment: Hi Osama. I only want to show the left side, yes Im using Material TextField. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem now
but couldn't find any answers
so i extended the `InputBorder` and this is what worked at last

```dart
class LeftSideInputBorder extends InputBorder {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  const LeftSideInputBorder({
    super.borderSide = const BorderSide(),
    this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.only(
      topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
    ),
  }) : assert(borderRadius != null);

  @override
  InputBorder copyWith({BorderSide? borderSide, BorderRadius? borderRadius}) {
    return LeftSideInputBorder(
      borderSide: borderSide ?? this.borderSide,
      borderRadius: borderRadius ?? this.borderRadius,
    );
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return Border(left: borderSide).dimensions;
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Border(left: borderSide)
        .getInnerPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Border(left: borderSide)
        .getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  /// True if this border will enclose the [InputDecorator]'s container.
  ///
  /// This property affects the alignment of container's contents. For example
  /// when an input decorator is configured with an [OutlineInputBorder] its
  /// label is centered with its container.
  @override
  // TODO: implement isOutline
  bool get isOutline => true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect,
      {double? gapStart,
      double gapExtent = 0.0,
      double gapPercentage = 0.0,
      TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    borderSide.toPaint());
    Border(left: borderSide).paint(canvas, rect);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return LeftSideInputBorder(borderSide: borderSide.scale(t));
  }
}
```

this is how it looks like
[widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjFHh.png)

but i wanted to make the border smaller
so i changed the `paint` to this

```dart
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect,
      {double? gapStart,
      double gapExtent = 0.0,
      double gapPercentage = 0.0,
      TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(
      rect.topLeft + Offset(0, 10.0),
      rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, 10.0),
    );
    Border(left: borderSide).paint(canvas, rect);
  }
```

this is the updated code looks like [widget with spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2zz.png)